# Typescript for loop error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm new to Angular and Typescript, I'm getting error with the for loop. Could someone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

```
steps=[];
totalNumberofSteps=3;
for (let idx = 0; idx <= totalNumberofSteps; idx++) {
    this.steps.push({ ordinal:idx, name: (idx == this.totalNumberofSteps) ? 'Finish' : idx});

  };
```

**Error:**
Error on Visual Code IDE

[ts] Duplicate identifier 'idx'.

[ts] Duplicate identifier 'idx'.

[ts] ',' expected.

-[ts] A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.

-(parameter) idx:number

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write statements like `for` loops in class bodies. They have to go in the constructor or a method body

```
class C {
    constructor() {
    }

    // Invalid
    for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

    }
}
```

vs

```
class C {
    constructor() {
        // OK
        for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but it was valid in Angulrjs right ? 

   $scope.$base.registerController('SomeCtrl', $scope.$id);
        SomeService.getSomeViewModel().then(function (result) {
            if (result.IsSuccessful) {
                
            }
        });
  
    $scope.currentStep = parseInt($location.hash() || 1);
    $scope.totalNumberOfSteps = 3;
    $scope.steps = [];
    for (var idx = 1; idx <= $scope.totalNumberOfSteps; idx++) {
        $scope.steps.push({ ordinal: idx, name: (idx == $scope.totalNumberOfSteps) ? 'Finish' : idx });
    }
}

Comment: $ { } ( ) ) ( ) { 9#$@ #! * &*@ { ? } }{{ | | { #@  { } !! | 9 $1 3= 5

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, you must to replace from `;` to `:` in condition syntax, like this code:

```
class TestCode {
    execute() {
        let steps = [];
        let totalNumberofSteps=3;

        for (let idx = 0; idx <= totalNumberofSteps; idx++) {
            steps.push({
                ordinal:idx,
                name: (idx == totalNumberofSteps) ? 'Finish' : idx
            });

            console.log(steps);
        }
    }
}

let test = new TestCode();
test.execute();
```

Comment: Sorry, that was my typing mistake here. but I have ":" in my .ts file

Comment: Could you post the whole code? I tested this code and is working fine for me. I changed my answer posting the whole code.

Comment: export class SampledataComponent implements OnInit {

      sampledata = [];

      constructor(private _sampledataservice: SampledataService) { }

      ngOnInit() {  

        this._sampledataservice.getData()
          .subscribe(resData => { 
            this.sampledata = resData;});
      }

      steps=[];
      totalNumberofSteps=3;
      for (let idx = 0; idx <= totalNumberofSteps; idx++) {
        this.steps.push({ ordinal:idx, name: (idx == this.totalNumberofSteps) ? 'Finish' : idx});
        
      };

    }

Comment: ah ok, I got it now, you must to put your code inside a method, you can't use it outside of a method or constructor.

Comment: I had something like this in Angularjs, converting to angular 5, would it be a good idea to add in constructor?   $scope.$base.registerController('SomeCtrl', $scope.$id);
        SomeService.getSomeViewModel().then(function (result) {
            
        });
  
    $scope.currentStep = parseInt($location.hash() || 1);
    $scope.totalNumberOfSteps = 3;
    $scope.steps = [];
    for (var idx = 1; idx <= $scope.totalNumberOfSteps; idx++) {
        $scope.steps.push({ ordinal: idx, name: (idx == $scope.totalNumberOfSteps) ? 'Finish' : idx });
    }
}

Comment: I really think that a good approach is create a method and call this method in the constructor.